# jQuery post function not working consistently (drops data)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem posting data using jquery.  The function seems to be very buggy.

ie/ sometimes my form will post and the data will get stored while at other times it doesn't store at all...

HERE'S THE JS:

```
function createEntry(){

    item_title = $('#item_title').val();
    item_description = $('#item_description').val();
    item_category = $('#item_category').val();

    $('#status').html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' border=0> Adding Entry").show();

    $.post("crud.php",{postvar:1, action:'createEntry', item_title:item_title, item_description:item_description, item_category:item_category}, function(html) { 
        $("#status").empty();    
        $("#status").append(html).fadeOut(2000);
        getAddedEntry();

    });

    $('#entry_textbox').clear();

}
```

HERE'S THE PHP:

```
 if ($_POST['action'] == 'createEntry') {

    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_title']);
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_description']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_category']);

    $entry = "INSERT INTO items (title, description, category) VALUES ('$title','$description','$category')";  

    if (!mysql_query($entry,$conn)){
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    else {
        mysql_close($conn);
        echo "Entry Added!";
    }
```

Comment: $("#status").append(html).fadeOut(2000);;
here's your potential problem!

Comment: I've removed the extra ';' - is that what you're referring to? It still doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the entries that you put in your form. It can not work one time and not next time. Maybe if you put a " or other unescaped sybmols it breaks the jquery post data.

You could use that `$("#your_form_id").serialize();` just add postvar:1 and action:'createEntry' as hidden fields.

Comment: No I've tried posting the exact same data and it might posts one time and not the next!

Comment: Hmm that is strange. Do you use Firefox with Firebug to track the requests and what they response?